# Which is the 5-adic number$\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be defined by the following;

$a = \cdots 431212$,

$b = \cdots 013233$.

$a$ and $b$ satisfy $x^2 + 1 = 0$ in base $5$.

Which is the 5-adic integer $\sqrt{-1}$?

If $a$ is the 5-adic integer $\sqrt{-1}$, $b$ is the 5-adic integer $ -
 \sqrt{-1}$?

If $b$ is the 5-adic integer $\sqrt{-1}$, $a$ is the 5-adic integer $ -
 \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Are these $5$-adic numbers in base $5$? Which one of these do you prefer as your square root of $-1$?

Comment: It is entirely a matter of preference, just like it's a matter of preference which root of $x^2 +1 = 0$ over the real numbers that we choose to call $i$. Unless you know of some objective criterion (like positive / negative) which one fulfills and not the other that may be used to separate the two.

Comment: What kind of representation of $x$ and $y$ is this?

Comment: @k.stm The [5-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) numbers, which is base $5$ with allowing infinite "decimals" to the left instead of to the right.

Comment: @Arthur I know $5$-adic numbers. I was wondering how these represent $5$-adic numbes: Are they meant to be extended periodically to the left?

Comment: @k.stm Not any more than the real number $\sqrt2 = 1.4142\ldots$ is meant to be extended periodically to the right, I'd guess. That being said, the wording is a bit unfortunate, I'll agree. $x$ and $y$ should've been defined as the roots of $a^2 + 1 = 0$, and then specified with an expansion instead of the other way around. But surely you've seen enough unfortunate wordings on this site to see through that.

Comment: Pari/GP gives the following  `w=teichmuller(2 +O(5^8)) `, (answer) `2 + 5 + 2*5^2 + 5^3 + 3*5^4 + 4*5^5 + 2*5^6 + 3*5^7 + O(5^8)` then the square : `w^2 ` gives `4 + 4*5 + 4*5^2 + 4*5^3 + 4*5^4 + 4*5^5 + 4*5^6 + 4*5^7 + O(5^8)` which equals $-1$ in the 5-adics. Note that the 5-adic-coefficients of $w$ are not periodic. So Pari/GP gives your first solution. But I think, this is just convention...

Comment: This is a good question: is there a widely-known $p$-adic convention for "the" square root, similar to the "principal" square root used for complex numbers?

Comment: Take a sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}/5^n \mathbb{Z}$ with $ a_n \equiv a_m \bmod 5^m$ when $m \le n$. Then $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ fulfills $a^2 = (-1,-1,-1,\ldots)= (5-1,5^2-1,5^3-1, \ldots)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ iff $\forall n, a_n^2 \equiv -1 \bmod 5^n$

Comment: @GEdgar there is no order relation which is compatible with the ring operations and the p-adic metric, so there's no corresponding concept.

Comment: @GuillaumeDufay Neither is in $\mathbb{C}$, yet there is a square root that people call the principal branch. In modular arithmetic, some people call $x^{(p+1)/4}$ then principal branch of the square root of $x$ modulo the prime $p$.

Comment: @plop But there is in $\mathbb R$.  It's relative to this order that the principal branch of the square root in $\mathbb C$ may be defined.  I wasn't familiar the convention in modular arithmetic you mentioned; could you cite some use of it?  Presumably it could be extended to an analogous convention for p-adic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either $a$ or $b$ can be used as $\sqrt{-1}$.