# How do I differentiate between $\sqrt{5}$ and $-\sqrt{5}$ in the $11$-adics - and should I even try to?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I've been playing around with the $11$-adic numbers lately, and in particular, the values of $\sqrt{5}$. I have two different approximations of this value:

- $a_1=\ ...937785904$A$44_{11}$
- $a_2=\ ...1733251$A$6067_{11}$

Of course, as how in the real numbers the equation $x^2-5=0$ has two solutions ($\sqrt{5}$ and $-\sqrt{5}$), the same equation has two solutions in the 11-adics, as shown above. In my mind, it makes sense that these two solutions match up with the two solutions in the reals, down the the fact that $a_1+a_2=0$.

However, if that is the case, which is negative, and which is positive?

Part of me feels like this is a silly question to ask. In the $p$-adics, the line between negatives and positives can be blurred. For instance, in the $11$-adics, $...11111_{11}\equiv-\frac{1}{10}$, whereas $...11112_{11}\equiv\frac{9}{10}$. There's not the "luxury", so to speak, of being able to tell between one and the other by checking if there's a negative sign or not.

But still, something nags at me that the two are different numbers where one is the negative of the other, and I don't know which one's which. I can't find any clever little trick to suss out which is negative and which is positive. Doing $(1+a_n)^2$ yields $6+2a_n$, as one would expect, but this is of little value for our purposes.

All this leads up to the question, is there even any real *purpose* in trying to figure this out? In the reals, the equation $x^2-5=0$ has two roots, $b_1$ and $b_2$ whose sum is $0$. This is the same in the $11$-adics. In the real numbers, one being negative and one being positive is of consequence, because those concepts *mean* something. We can say definitively that $b_1<b_2$ even though $|b_1|=|b_2|$. The same cannot always be said of the $11$-adics, as is seen here. So, is there a concrete answer, and in the grand scheme of things, does there *need* to be one?

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381141/which-is-the-5-adic-number-sqrt-1

Comment: There is no meaning to the question.  There is a convention in $\mathbb R$ showing how to choose one of the two square roots.  But there is no such convention in $\mathbb Q_{11}$.  Similarly, in the extension of $\mathbb R$ by appending zeros for $X^2+1$, there is no way to distingulsh the two zeros.

Comment: The question is the same in the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{11}$ or the cyclic group of $10$-th roots of unity. Note that in $1+11\Bbb{Z}_{11}$ there is a canonical choice of square root (the one which is again in $1+11\Bbb{Z}_{11}$)

Comment: Some people do call $5^{(11+1)/4}\equiv 4\pmod{11}$ the principal branch of the square root. That would make your $a_1$ the principal branch. Be very suspicious when someone tells tells you that something is not done, or doesn't exist, in terms of terminology or definitions. Almost always false.

Comment: @owl good take. Unfortunately this approach works (as written) only when $p$ is one less than a multiple of $4$. We're still stuck e.g. with $\sqrt{14}$ in $5$-adics.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4006006/96384, especially paragraph 3 et seq. of my answer.

Comment: Compare this to the situation in $\mathbb{C}$, where every nonzero number has two distinct square roots, but the field isn't ordered.

Comment: @anomaly But if you take $\mathbb C$ as a topological field, $\mathbb R$ sits canonically in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reasonable notion of "positive" in the $p$-adic numbers, in the following precise sense. Say that a field $F$ is **[formally real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field)** if it admits a total order $\le$ making it an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field), meaning that $a \ge b$ iff $a - b \ge 0$ and that the set of positive elements $\{ a \in F : a > 0 \}$ contains $1$ and is closed under addition and multiplication (there are a few equivalent ways to state this definition).

> **Claim:** $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not formally real, for any prime $p$.

*Proof.* In any ordered field, either $a \ge 0$ or $a \le 0$ (trichotomy). If $a \ge 0$ then $a^2 \ge 0$, and if $a \le 0$ then $-a \ge 0$ so $(-a)^2 = a^2 \ge 0$. So squares are non-negative, and so a sum of squares must be non-negative. In particular, $-1$ is negative and so cannot be a sum of squares. (This is an equivalent way to define formally real fields.) But

$$(1 - 4p)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{n \ge 0} {\frac{1}{2} \choose k} (-4p)^k$$

converges $p$-adically for every prime $p$ (the factor of $4$ is needed only to handle the case $p = 2$), from which it follows that we can write

$$-1 = \sqrt{1 - 4p}^2 + (4p - 2) 1^2$$

as a sum of at most $4p - 3$ squares in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. (We can do much better than this; by applying [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) we can replace $4p - 3$ with $5$, and I think applying it more carefully we should be able to replace $5$ with $4$. But we don't need to.)

But this means that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not formally real as desired. $\Box$

So, all we can really say is that one of the square roots is $4 \bmod 11$ and the other one is $7 \bmod 11$ and that's all. There is no reasonable sense in which one is "positive" or "larger" than the other. This is analogous to the situation with the two square roots of $-1$ in the complex numbers $i$ and $-i$, which also don't really come in any kind of preferred or distinguished order. (This is a little disguised if you define $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}[i]/(i^2 + 1)$ since this definition privileges $i$ over $-i$ explicitly, but there are alternatives that avoid this. You can, for example, define $\mathbb{C}$ as the algebra of matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ of the form $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ -b & a \end{array} \right]$.)

Comment: $-1$ is already a sum of *two* squares in $\mathbb Q_p$ for $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$, and is itself a square in $\mathbb Q_p$ for $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$. Only in $\mathbb Q_2$ do we need four squares.

Comment: @Torsten: I couldn't find a nice argument for $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$; what do you have in mind? I see that $-1 = 1 + (-2)$ works if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 8$.

Comment: See user Ted's beautiful answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149520/96384.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Accepting some theory, one can actually find solutions where the squares are integers: Since the squares in $\mathbb F_p^\times$ form a subgroup of index $2$, there is at least one $n \in \{1, \dots, p-2 \}$ such that $n$ is a square (in $\mathbb Z_p$) and $n+1$ is not. But then, if $-1$ is not a square itself, $-n-1$ is a square (modulo $p$, and then in $\mathbb Z_p$ via Hensel). And $-1 = n + (-n-1)$.

Answer (score 6):

It is a good exercise to check that the closure of the set of negative rational numbers in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is all of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It follows that there is no meaningful notion of "negative" in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

This doesn't mean that we are hopeless and there is no way at all to tell one square root of $5$ from the other in $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$. For instance, one is 4 mod $11$ and the other is $7$ mod $11$. You could define a continuous "square root map" on $(\mathbb{Z}_p^\times)^2$ (the set of $p$-adic units that are squares) by, for example, insisting on always taking the square root with least positive residue. I don't know of practical implications of such a map, though, unlike in the real case.

Answer (score 2):

If the radicand is $\equiv1\bmod p$ for odd $p$ (meaning the $p$-adic representaion ends in $1$)*, then we may plug in the Maclaurin series

$\sqrt{1+x}=1+(x/2)-(x^2/8)+...$

and will converge to a specific value, which will be one of the square roots, specifically having the form $1+py$ where $|py|<1$ in the $p$-adic norm. We could call such a root the "positive" square root in the sense that the multiplicative identity $1$ absolutely dominates the series and its sum. But there are two caveats:

1. Not all $p$-adic integers will lend themselves to a convergent Maclaurin series even if roots exist; as noted above the radicand has to have residue $1\bmod p$. We thus cannot universally define a "positive" root in this way. For instance, the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1+4}$, rendered into $11$-adics, will not converge to either $11$-adic square root of $5$.
2. Because of the difference between $p$-adic and real norms, what are ordinarily negative numbers can appear "positive" through their difference from the multiplicative identity having a reduced $p$-adic norm. Thus in your $11$-adic example, $\sqrt{1+99}=\sqrt{100}$ gives a convergent Maclaurin series -- whose sum is $-10$ instead of $+10$. If we use the modification denoted by * for the case $p=2$, the $2$-adic square root of $1+8=9$ from the Maclaurin series is $-3$ instead of $+3$.

*For $p=2$ we would need the radicand to be $\equiv1\bmod 8$, thus to end $2$-adically in $...001$. The sum of the series then converges to the root $2$-adically closest to the multiplicative identity, having the form $1+4y$.

Answer (score 2):

You may also wonder whether it is possible to define a canonical square root on $(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$.

When $p$ is odd, there is a canonical choice of square root for elements in $\mathbb Z_p$ that are $1$ modulo $p$, because
$$\begin{align}1 + p \mathbb Z_p & \to 1 + p \mathbb Z_p \\
x & \mapsto x^2\end{align}$$
is an isomorphism. Now $\mathbb Q_p^\times \cong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb F_p^{\times} \times (1 + p \mathbb Z_p)$ canonically. So to define a canonical square root on all of $(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$ becomes therefore equivalent to defining a canonical square root on $(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2$.

When $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ there is a unique choice of square root that gives a group homomorphism $\sqrt{}: (\mathbb F_p^\times)^2 \to \mathbb F_p^\times$. Explicitly,
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{} : (\mathbb F_p^\times)^2 &\to \mathbb F_p^\times \\
x & \mapsto x^{(p+1)/4} \,. \end{align}$$
Alternatively, when $g$ is any primitive root mod $p$, send $g^2$ to $-g$ and extend multiplicatively to $g^{2k}$.

When $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, no such group homomorphism exists, or we would reach the classical high school student's paradox that
$$1 = \sqrt{1^2} = \sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{-1}^2 = -1 \,. $$

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading in Neal Koblitz's book that there are examples of rational polynomials where you can feed a rational approximation into Newton-Raphson and get convergence to a rational root, but the real and p-adic versions give different ones.